# Unwanted space in table cell when another cell has a tag within it

Tags: html-table, flexbox

I'm having trouble understanding why the two chunks of HTML below render differently. The yellow and pink table is missing a BR tag, and flows efficiently, the green and blue table has the `<BR>` tag in the middle of the text in the blue cell, and has unwanted space in the green cell. I've tried rendering as flex boxes and tables, and they render the same way. I've tried different browsers, and they render the same way.

What rule is being followed in the green and blue layout that causes the whitespace in the green cell?

How can I get rendering like the yellow-and-pink case and use `<BR>` tags? I'm actually after `<P>` tags, but let's just talk about `<BR>` tags, which I figure are the most simple case.

```html
<html><body>

<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row;">
<div style="background-color: green;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<br/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</div>
</div>

<br/>

<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: yellow;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</td>
<td style="background-color: pink;">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<xbr/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</td>
</table>
<br/>

</body></html>
```

Screenshot: [image: The yellow and pink table is missing a BR tag, and flows efficiently]

If a height is assigned to a div, the whitespace is not removed (see the darker green below), and if a `<br>` tag is allowed into a table which has a height on the cell, the whitespace is split between the top and bottom of the cell (see the lighter green below) - but the height attribute doesn't affect the rendering anyway: [image]
This behaviour is exhibited in FireFox 80.0 and Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's going on:

1. Inside of the `div` with `display: flex; flex-flow: row` you have two children, the green and the blue `div`s.
2. The browser calculates their individual widths (it's the width because `flex-flow: row`) as follows:

   - The calculation of the green `div`'s width is straight forward. It's the width of the whole text on one line.
     => **`greenWidth`**
   - The calculation of the blue `div` is a little bit more involved because of the `<br>`. This causes the text to be split in two. The browser then calculates the widths of these two bits of text that they would take on one line each. Then it takes the wider of these.
     => **`blueWidth`**
3. Both, the green and the blue box have their default value for `flex-basis` which is `auto`. For the green box, the browser takes **`greenWidth`** and for the blue box it takes **`blueWidth`** as the result of `auto`.

I still haven't come up with an actual solution but maybe, based on the above, you might be able to figure something out.

Comment: Yes, yes I can - after much fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

In the flex-box the items are stretched to the height of the container (if height of items is not defined). However, You can change this behaviour by gibing the green div a height.
Suppose the height is 100px;

```
<html><body>
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row;">
<div style="background-color: green; height: 100px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
 laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
 architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<br/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci 
velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam 
aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem 
ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</div>
</div>

<br/>

<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: yellow;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</td>
<td style="background-color: pink;">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque 
laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<xbr/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci 
velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam 
aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem 
ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>

</body></html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See my just added example of it not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4262276/christian) pointed in the right direction. Understanding that the problem is down to sizing being affected by tags, I allowed the browser to size the un-tagged content, but hid its rendering.

The "solution" is to have two text bodies, one rendering with tags and the other without. The text without tags is `color:transparent;` and positioned with normal text flow. The text with tags is rendered on top of the document text flow in the location of the transparent text by using a `z-index` higher than the normal text. There is a chance that the text with tags will overflow the table, so layout your page with this possibility under consideration (or pad the text without tags a little):

```html
<html><body>

<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row;">

<div style="background-color: #FFA;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>

<div style="position: relative; background-color: #FDD;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:2;">
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<br/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</div>

<div style="color:transparent;">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
<xbr/>
Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
</div>
</div>

</div>

</body></html>
```

[image]